# Print biggest and smallest numbers ,until -1 is given

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, int

It works, but if you don't enter any number smaller than 0 it doesn't print the smaller value and prints 0.

```
int max = 0;
int min = 0;
int a;

printf("Enter a number:\n");
scanf("%d", &a);

while (a != -1){
        if (a < min){
            min = a;
        }

        if (a > max){
            max = a;
        }
        scanf("%d", &a);
}
printf("Your largest number is %d. Your smallest number is %d.", max, min);
```

Comment: Only numbers less than zero are smaller than zero, so you won't record the smallest properly if you initialize `min` to `0` but the values entered are all positive. (If all the values are smaller than -1, you won't initialize `max` properly either!) It would be better to use `min = max = a;` after you read the first value.  Alternatively, initialize `min` to `INT_MAX` from `<limits.h>` and `max` to `INT_MIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your initial `min` is zero so *no* positive value is going to be less than that.

You're better off changing your loop construct so that initial value is loaded no matter what, something like:

```
int a, min = 0, max = 0, first = 1; // Force first number to be used.
printf ("Enter a number:\n");
scanf ("%d", &a);
while (a != -1) {
    if (first || a < min) min = a;
    if (first || a > max) max = a;
    first = 0;                      // Reset after first number.
    scanf ("%d", &a);
}
printf ("Largest is %d, smallest is %d.\n", max, min);
```

---

You should probably *also* check the return value from `scanf` so as to catch non-integer input. That's a way to have more robust code but, for educational programs, it's probably okay (at least as long as you understand the implications).

This could be as simple as replacing:

```
scanf ("%d", &a)
```

with something like:

```
if (scanf ("%d", &a) != 1) {
    puts ("Invalid input.");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Remove `first` and initialize `min = INT_MAX` and `max = INT_MIN` (from `<limits.h>`, of course)?  Or simply set `min = max = a;` after the `scanf()` outside the loop (again deleting `first`)?